# C++ Project Structure in UNIX/Linux environment: test and app folder

Tags: c++, project-management, linux, project-structure

I am trying to figure out the right project structure for `C++` and I am working on Ubuntu using `CMake`. I mostly work on AI/ Robotics/ Data Science. Assume that I want to generate executables and libraries. I have looked at a few links including [link1](https://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/), [link2](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/basics/structure.html), [link3](https://medium.com/heuristics/c-application-development-part-1-project-structure-454b00f9eddc). I am also looking at [OpenCV git repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) to gain more understanding. I understand that some aspects of this question can be opinion-based. But I still think there are enough parts that can be answered specifically. If not please let me know if there is another stack exchange site more suitable for this question (`Code Review`?).

1) Regarding `test` folder: Consider writing code to perform camera calibration. Assume that the test for the calibration procedure is done using calculation of re-projection error or something similar. In this case do we include the code for this test inside the test folder? Or is this folder only to perform tests from a software engineering perspective; things like time complexity, space complexity, edge cases, bugs?

2) Regarding `app`/`apps` folder: What exactly goes in here? My initial impression was that it is the source for final executable/ application. But `OpenCV` seems to have all kinds of files inside this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` folder in a repository typically contains the code to test the system from an engineering perspective: does the system still work as it should. This code is typically *not* delivered to end-users or recipients of a binary-only distribution.

For an `app` or `apps` folder, there is no convention on what to put in there. It seems OpenCV uses that folder to house a collection of helper applications.